# How to select and get attributes of video and audio element while iterating through DOM in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui

I tried this for given html element.

```
    $('#dynamicformdata').each(function() {

          console.log(this.type);
     })

  <div id="dynamicformdata">
    <video width="320" height="240" >
        <source src="movie.mp4" type="video/mp4">
        <source src="movie.ogg" type="video/ogg">

   </video>
 </div>
```

How to get all attribute of this video tag inside div.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```js
    $('#dynamicformdata').each(function() {
      // "this" in the first function refers to the div
      console.log(this);

      // call a second function for every source tag in every video in the dynamicformdata tag
      $('video>source', this).each(function() {
        // "this" referes to a source tag
        console.log(this.type);
      });
    });
```

If you want to get all types as an array:

```js
    $('#dynamicformdata').each(function() {
      var types = [];
      $('video>source', this).each(function() {
        types.push(this.type);
      });
      // logs the div element and all found types (duplicates not filtered out)
      console.log(this, types);
    });
```

Comment: so if i add "video>source" will this loop still capable to select other input elements ?

Comment: What is the complete code? Was it able in the first place?

Comment: I have  a div element inside it there are many elements like text box etc including audio and video i don't have their id's so i have to loop through each element. i am able to loop through input elements but audio and video is not fetched by each loop. so how can i select this element as well ?

Comment: Ok, thanks for that info. You will need two loops. I'll edit my answer. Wait a minute or two.

Comment: @deepakmishra If that was helpful and you used this answer to solve your problem, it would be nice if you mark that answer as accepted. Of cause only if you want. It would not only help me but also others who have the same problem and come across this question while searching.